# How to get the closed form form a nonlinear complicated equation from python?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am looking for the closed-form of x from the following nonlinear equation:

```py
1/{e^[a*(d-x)]+1}+ln(1/x-1)*b=c
```

Does python solve the nonlinear equation with algebra rather than the numerical data? or are there any useful and efficient tools to solve that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It would be great to see what you have tried in your python code and which packages you are using. The best way to have people help you is to provide a Minimum Working Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to have a closed form solution. Is there a reason to think that there would be one?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure that. But the closed-form of x is a key point for my subsequent research and I want to get this. The reason I think it exists is that there is a unique x for each numerical setting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the `Sympy` module for algebraic solutions of equations? Unfortunately I am not sure it can solve your own equation, but in case it can help you later:

```
In [1]: from sympy import exp, log, solve
In [2]: from sympy.abc import a,b,c,d,x
In [3]: solve( 1/(exp(a*(d-x))+1) + log(1/x-1)*b - c, x)
```

which does not find any solution here (look at the last line below):

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 solve( 1/(exp(a*(d-x))+1) + log(1/x-1)*b-c, x)
>
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py in solve(f,
>   *symbols, **flags)    1063     ###########################################################################    1064     if bare_f:
>   -> 1065         solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)    1066     else:    1067         solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)
>
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py in _solve(f,
>   *symbols, **flags)    1632     1633     if result is False:
>   -> 1634         raise NotImplementedError('\n'.join([msg, not_impl_msg % f]))    1635     1636     if flags.get('simplify', True):
>
> NotImplementedError: multiple generators [exp(-a*x), log(-1 + 1/x)] No
>   algorithms are implemented to solve equation b*log(-1 + 1/x) - c +
>   1/(exp(a*(d - x)) + 1)

Of course you could expect something like *Mathematica* to be more powerful than *Sympy*, but actually:

```
Wolfram Language 12.0.0 Engine for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= Solve[ 1/(Exp[a*(d-x)]+1) + Log[1/x - 1]*b == c, x]                     

Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

                    1                     1
Out[1]= Solve[-------------- + b Log[-1 + -] == c, x]
                   a (d - x)              x
              1 + E
```